# How to run a function when reloading react

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, amazon-cognito, refresh

I am using congnito to authenticate And I'm trying to create a privateRoute.

I'm currently using redux and amazon-cognito-identity-js

```js
export const cognitoSignIn = async ({
  email,
  password,
}: SignInInfo): Promise<CognitoUserSession> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(email, password);

    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: email.trim(),
      Password: password.trim(),
    });
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
      Username: email,
      Pool: userPool,
    });

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        if (!currentUser) {
          currentUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
        }

        currentUser.getSession((err: any, session: CognitoUserSession) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(session);
          }
        });
      },
      onFailure: reject,
    });
  });
};
```

```js
export const signIn =
  (signinInfo: SignInInfo) =>
  async (dispatch: Dispatch<UpdateToken | UpdateError>) => {
    try {
      const auth: CognitoUserSession = await cognitoSignIn(signinInfo);
      const accessToken = auth.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(accessToken));
      dispatch(updateToken(accessToken));
    } catch (error: any) {
      dispatch(updateError(error));
    }
  };
```

My question has nothing to do with the code above.

When you do cognito signin, a token is created in localstorage.

when refreshed,
To get the state of a token in localstorage, you need to use the cognito getSession function.

But the getSession function is an async function

How can I get the data by executing the function before it is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a "loading state" that is rendert as long as you are waiting for your async function.

E.g.:

```
const example = () => {
    useState[isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const asyncFunction = async() => {
            setIsLoading(true)
            await(something...)
            setIsloading(false)
        }
        asyncFuntion()  
    }, [])

    if(isLoading) return (e.g LoadingSpinner)

    return (your component)
}
```